# Accessing model attributes in ActiveSupport::Concern module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some models which share the same functionality just on other paths. So I decided to put these methods in a module and set the path in the model. My problem is that I'm not able to access the attribute in my module.

model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageModel

  image_dir = "jobs"
end
```

module:

```
module ImageModel
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def delete_image
      unless pic_link == "" || pic_link == nil
        begin
          if File.delete(Rails.root.join("public", "images", image_dir, pic_link))
            return true
          else
            return false
          end
        rescue
          return true #an error occured but when the image does not exist we still return true
        end
      end

      return true
    end

    def replace_image(new_image)
      File.open(Rails.root.join("public", "images", image_dir, new_image.original_filename), "wb") do |f|
        if f.write new_image.read
          delete_image
          pic_link = new_image.original_filename
          return true #everything went fine
        else
          return false #return false if new image could not be written
        end
      end
    end
end
```

The error i get:

```
undefined local variable or method `image_dir' for #<Job:0x007f8a93b9e8d8>
```

on this line:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join("public", "images", image_dir, new_image.original_filename), "wb") do |f|
```

Did I miss something or did I oversee something important?

Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the design of module still have room to improve. But for this specific question, here is the quickfix.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageModel

  def image_dir
    "jobs"
  end
end
```

Comment: @soupdiver, my pleasure :) My suggestion for first step of refactoring is to make the module self sufficient. i.e. all of the methods inside this module except normal ActiveRecord instance methods are better to be callable inside itself, aka have a default value. You can overwrite them in your model but that should not be the model's responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `image_dir = "jobs"` in the module itself. because you are including your module in your model, and your module is not able to get the declaration, you have done in your model.

Or you can change your `delete_image` method to take parameters :

```
def delete_image(image_dir)
      unless pic_link == "" || pic_link == nil
        begin
          if File.delete(Rails.root.join("public", "images", image_dir, pic_link))
            return true
          else
            return false
          end
        rescue
          return true #an error occured but when the image does not exist we still return true
        end
      end

      return true
    end
```

and where you are calling that method, pass an argument like this:

```
 delete_image("jobs")
```

same in the case of `replace_image` method:

```
 def replace_image(new_image, image_dir)
      File.open(Rails.root.join("public", "images", image_dir, new_image.original_filename), "wb") do |f|
        if f.write new_image.read
          delete_image
          pic_link = new_image.original_filename
          return true #everything went fine
        else
          return false #return false if new image could not be written
        end
      end
    end
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: But my plan is to really extend my module and that's why I want to access the attributes in this extensions. When I go to parameters I must put this logic in my controller but I want to isolate this in the model. Is there no way to achieve this?